# Application posts to page feed returns invalid post_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When an app (i.e., mine, FriendCaster, GraphAPI) posts to the feed for a page a user likes, the post_id is returned & I can always see the message show up on the page -- when viewed from the browser.

When I attempt to read the page feed from any apps however, those same posts don't all show up.  Sometimes I'll see the first couple of posts from the app, then nothing after.

Furthermore, if I try to use Graph API Explorer to show the status with the post_id returned from the successful post, it either returns an empty object, or the generic "Unsupported get request.", code": 100.

I've tried all settings for the app default privacy, with no change.

I've also tried setting all permissions on the app, but no improvement.

Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe the user making the post has "opted out" of the Facebook platform, as they call it - that would explain why their posts are not visible to the (or any other) app.

Comment: That would make sense, however the message is still visible in the browser.  Also, several of the posts are from my account (& co-workers) who have not opted-out of Facebook.

Comment: Sorry, didn't finish that comment...

It appears likely that the cause is FB's spam filter, and allowing the posts to still be visible on the website is a bug.  Similarly, once the spam filter kicks in, the error indicating too many posts should be returned instead of a valid post_id.  I'm following up on the FB bug site.

Answer (score 1):

Opened a Facebook [bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/350672038370328?browse=search_513d1bc14bc216185501923) with this information & the cause appears to be the spam filter kicking in (albeit a bit clunkily)

`This is by design. Posting too many times to a page repeatedly will be marked as spam.`

Unfortunately, there isn't a way for a page to whitelist apps that it would allow frequent posts from.

As mentioned in my comments above, this raises a couple of other issues that I'll follow-up on at the FB site.